# Enlarging columns with no vertical line size with a parallel contents

Tags: tables

In fact, I want to enlarge a table column with no vertical line and also having a parallel content and not a center contents in the table. Here is the code:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p,numbers,sort,compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



 \begin{document}



\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{ parameters }
\label{tab:Parameters 2}
\begin{tabular}{ l c c c }
\toprule
Parameters & Value & Parameters & Value\\
\midrule
  P1  & 500 & K1 & 0.01  \\
 P2 & 2200 & K2 &  0.01 \\
  P3 & 6 & K3 &  33 \\
  P4 & 20$\times$$10^{-3}$ &    K4 &  0.15 \\
 P5 & X & K5 & 0.1 \\
 P6  & 24.2 & K6 &  0.1\\
 P7 & 40.3 & K7 &  40\\
 P8 & 12.1  & K8 &  0.23\\
 P9 & 1 & K9 &  0.52\\
 P10 & 1$\times$$10^{4}$ & K10 &  0.9\\
  P11 & 24  & K11 &  0\\
    P12 & 50  & 0 &  0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Here is  what I want to do :
[image]

Comment: To have left aligned content you should replace `c c c` by `l l l` (3 times letter L).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, where each column has width equal to 20% of the line width, and has content align to left.

[image]

Observe the way to type the scientific notation in math mode.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p,numbers,sort,compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


 \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{parameters}
\label{tab:Parameters 2}
\begin{tabular}{p{.2\linewidth}p{.2\linewidth}p{.2\linewidth}p{.2\linewidth}}
\toprule
Parameters & Value & Parameters & Value\\
\midrule
 P1  & 500 & K1 & 0.01  \\
 P2  & 2200 & K2 &  0.01 \\
 P3  & 6 & K3 &  33 \\
 P4  & $20\times10^{-3}$ &    K4 &  0.15 \\
 P5  & X & K5 & 0.1 \\
 P6  & 24.2 & K6 &  0.1\\
 P7  & 40.3 & K7 &  40\\
 P8  & 12.1  & K8 &  0.23\\
 P9  & 1 & K9 &  0.52\\
 P10 & $1\times10^{4}$ & K10 &  0.9\\
 P11 & 24  & K11 &  0\\
 P12 & 50  & 0 &  0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sigur what did you mean by the scientific notation in math mode ?

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj, like here: `20$\times$$10^{-3}$`. You typed `$` too much. Simply use one pair of dollar signs: `$20 \times 10^{-3}$` for the whole value.

Comment: The fourth column how can I make it in the right I don't want the space between the vertical line and fourth column

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj, replace the last `p{.2\linewidth}` by `r`.

Comment: I did it but the contents in the fourth column is parallel from the right and not from the left

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj So, use `l` then, for `left`.